# count of numeric values by column with data.table (R)

Tags: r, data.table

```
DC<-data.table(l=c(0,0,1,4,5),d=c(1,2,0,0,1),y=c(0,1,0,1,7))
```

Hello,
how can I get a count of a particular value in a column using data.table?
I tried the following:

```
DC[, lapply(.SD, function(x) length(which(DC==0)))]
```

But this returns the count of zeros in the entire dataset, not indexing by column. So, how do I index by column?
Thanks

Comment: `DC[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum( x == 0 ) ]`

Comment: `apply( DC == 0, 2, sum )`

Comment: `colSums(DC == 0)`

Comment: your code: `DC[, lapply(.SD, function(x) length(which(x==0)))] `

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very well formulated, but I think @Sathish answered it perfectly in the comments.

Let's write it here one more time: to me `colSums(DC == 0)` is one answer to the question.
All credit goes to @Sathish. Very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question, you'd like to form a frequency count of the values that comprise a given data table column. If that is true, let's say that you want to do so on column **d** of the data table you supplied:

```
> DC <- data.table(l=c(0,0,1,4,5), d=c(1,2,0,0,1), y=c(0,1,0,1,7))
> DC[, .N, by = d]
   d N
1: 1 2
2: 2 1
3: 0 2
```

Then, if you want the count of a particular value in **d**, you would do so by accessing the corresponding row of the above aggregation as follows:

```
> DC[, .N, by = d][d == 0, N]
[1] 2
```

Comment: I wasn't very clear probably. The previous comment adressed my issue. I wanted to apply a count of the zeros for each column, but typed DC==0 instead of x==0. Thanks for your reply by the way.